# Adding "Min:" to input field before default data

Tags: javascript, php, html

We have an input field on our online store, the code for which is below:

```
<input id="ets_gp_height" name="ets_gp_height" data-height="{$priceConfig.ets_gridprice_height}" class="form-control" value="{$priceConfig.ets_gridprice_height}"/>
```

This input field is a "height" box for products on our website, every product has a different minimum height and the tag {$priceConfig.ets_gridprice_height} generates the default minimum height which in turn gets the minimum price for the product.

We need to be able to add the word "Min:" before this default value, so however if we add it into the code as follows:

```
<input id="ets_gp_height" name="ets_gp_height" data-height="Min:{$priceConfig.ets_gridprice_height}" class="form-control" value="Min:{$priceConfig.ets_gridprice_height}"/>
```

It displays correctly e.g Min: 200, or Min: 300, but the price doesnt show.

Is there a way we can get the word Min: showing before the default height but so that the input field only takes account of the value itself and ignores the "Min:"

Thanks

Comment: If it is an input field, then you would allow the user to edit the word "Min" as well. This seems strange. If the word "Min" is intended to give meaning to the value that follows it, then put the word "Min" right before or after the `input` element, but not inside it. Alternatively you could use the `placeholder` attribute *instead of* the `value` attribute. Then the value of the input will remain blank, but the user will see the text. It will disappear when they start typing.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would do this using a label:

```html
<label for="test">Min:</label>
<input id="test" type="text">
```

You can also style it in a way that makes it look more like part of the input:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

label {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  border-right: 0;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background-color: #eee;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <label for="test">Min:</label>
  <input id="test" type="text">
</div>
```

If you want it seamless, just style the label as part of the input and make it clickable (the `for`-attribute does that for you. Or use sequence `<label>text<input /></label>`). Users probably won't notice it and you have less problems with your post values.

If you really **need** it to be in the input itself, although that is generally less user-friendly and might mess up your post-request, there is no way around js.

You could subscribe to the `onchange` event and make sure, that he did not move or delete the "Min" string. Or you use `keyDown` to stop that before it happens. Note that you will also have to check the type of the input, as that will obviously not work with e.g. `type="number"`.